# use of undeclared identifier semantic issue

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.3

i am stack in this error use of undeclared identifier vary common error and sometimes very easy to fix but i am anyway stack, probably i am watching in the wrong way.

I am trying to do a log book where people can write what they want and save in plist.

From a tableView, where I will show al the files saved, i will push to a xib view where the person can fill up the fields. I've already imported the .h for the new and from the .h where I define my keys.

Here where the error is coming out.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    name.text = [bookLog objectForKey:NAME_KEY];
    placeTextView.text = [bookLog objectForKey:PLACE_KEY];
    file1TextView.text = [bookLog objectForKey:FILE1_KEY];
    file2TextView.text = [bookLog objectForKey:FILE2_KEY];
 }
```

4 errors for bookLog 1 for each line and 1 for name.text, placeTextView.text, file1TextView.text, fileTextView.text.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the declarations of name, placeTextView, ... etc.  My guess is that you declared them as \@property's, then synthesized them with an alias, like this \@synthesize name=_name;

Comment: Hi Dahn ..   .h {
    
    NSDictionary *bookLog;
    IBOutlet UITextField *name;
    IBOutlet UITextView  *placeTextView;
    IBOutlet UITextView  *file1TextView;
    IBOutlet UITextView  *file2TextView;
}
\@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *bookLog;
\@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *name;
\@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView  *placeTextView;
\@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView  *file1TextView;
\@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView  *file2TextView;
\@end  ---   .m   \@synthesize bookLog, name, placeTextView, file1TextView, file2TextView;

Comment: Hmm.  I don't see anything wrong with what you posted in the question or the comment.  It might require taking a look at the entire .m and .h.  Can you post somewhere (like pastebin))?

Comment: Hi Danh.. I've posted on ((past bin)).. the question title is the same like here and my nick name is the same.. thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, i can't find it.  can you paste a link here?

Comment: Hi.. Chris212 did you check all the code in ((pastebin) ? I synthesised them in my diveLogDetails.h. About the declaration are you talking about viewWillAppear ? As that one is in the .m.

Comment: sorry it took so long to get back.  @chrisl212 is essentially right.  see my answer.

Comment: @Mitch1972 yes you did but you have to synthesize them in the .m not .h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties you refer to in diveLogTable.m are not members of the diveLogTable class, so the compiler sees them as undefined when you mention them there.  They are defined publicly on the diveLogDetails class, so they can be accessed there (or by asking an instance of that class for them).

The code that's not compiling can be moved into the diveLogDetails class.  It's what you want to do when *that* view controller's view will appear (set up the UIControls).  It will compile there, and it seems to make sense there.

It looks to me like you have some diveLog information held in the diveLog dictionary, and you'd like to present that data to the user and allow edits via the diveLogDetails class (it's conventional to start class names with a capital letter and name view controllers with that suffix, like this: DiveLogDetailsViewController).

The diveLog dictionary on the diveLogDetails class is the only property that ought to be public.  When you create the diveLogDetails VC, set the dictionary as you have it.

Let the diveLogDetails read the values from the dictionary, setup it's UIControls, alter the dictionary values when the user changes the values of the controls (and taps save, or whatever).  Upon return to the diveLogTable, the up-to-date values will be in the dictionary.

Comment: Hi Danh, it is fine the error disappeared. Thanks even for the tip about conventional stuff. I finished the program, I don't have any error but my program does not save the data, probablyI messed up something before. Now I will double check again everything. Is it too much if I will bother you again for your help if I can not fix my project. I will understand if you will no, probably you are already such as busy with your job.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think its because you didnt synthesize the propertys you are talking about in you .m it just says `@synthesize data1;` when it should synthesize all the properties you are having errors with also. (`@synthesize placeTextView;
@synthesize...`also, you made declarations in a .h file when you should declare in your .m